# Smashoperator on two limits of sums

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, math-operators

## Problem

This MWE with two sums, that have prolonged limits each:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    $\displaystyle x \wedge y =
    \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \ldots < i_p \leq n}
    \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < \ldots < j_q \leq n}
    a_{i_1 \ldots i_p} b_{j_1 \ldots j_q}
    \; \underbrace{e_{i_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge e_{i_p} \wedge e_{j_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge e_{j_q}}_{\text{is sometimes 0}}$    
\end{document}
```

produces a lot of space for the sums. Nevertheless the readability is bad, as the limits are too close to each other. Usage of `smashoperator{}` will lead to an error and one limit not showing any more.
I would much prefer the second formula (or also additionally smashed on the left side of the first sum).
[image: current result and desired result]

## Question

How can I produce the second formula in the picture? (or any other nice looking 'smashed' result)

### Edit

1) I found this (just the sums) code to be close to my desired result. However it yields an undefined control sequence error:

```
\smashoperator{\mathop{\smashoperator{\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \ldots < i_p \leq n}\sum}}_{\qquad 1 \leq j_1 < \ldots < j_q \leq n}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this?  with a little help from `\mathclap` and `stackengine`.  EDIT to replace `\ldots` with `\dots` and `\cdots`, per Mico's request.  I hope I interpreted his request in the right way...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
    $\displaystyle x \wedge y =\qquad
    \sum_{\mathclap{1 \leq i_1 < \dots < i_p \leq n}}\quad
    \sum_{\stackunder[5pt]{}{\scriptstyle\mathclap{1 \leq j_1 < \dots < j_q \leq n}}}
    a_{i_1 \dots i_p} b_{j_1 \dots j_q}
    \; \underbrace{e_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_p} \wedge e_{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{j_q}}_{\text{is sometimes 0}}$    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Do replace all `\ldots` instances with `\dots` -- some of them really need to be `\cdots` ...

Comment: Wow that was quick! I was just editing in some additional information when you posted this answer already. Looks very good! I have never used stackengine - does it misbehave with other packages (I do need quite a lot packages) ? Also, what does `\stackMath` in the preamble do?

Comment: @Mico , why replace the `\ldots` ? I don't see where `\cdots` would fit better.

Comment: @hillbilly  The `\stackMath` in the preamble tells `stackengine` to, by default, process its arguments in math mode.  I think the package is well behaved and, as I wrote it, you can always contact me with bug reports or feature requests.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for this quick answer - accepted! For the sake of curiosity, how would you tell mathclap to 'smash' the left side also ? ( I merely know that `smashoperator` has an option e.g. `[r]`)

Comment: @hillbilly It already smashed the left side.  You will note I added a `\qquad` after the `=`, to basically compensate for the smashed left side of the summation limit.

Comment: @hillbilly - In math typesetting, it's customary to place ellipses located between relational operators -- e.g., those between `<` symbols -- at a different height from ellipses between simple list items.

Comment: True ... excuse me for overlooking that. @Mico Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 9):

I'd simply use one summation sign; but also two can be used. I'd also avoid `\smashoperator`, unless space constraints require squeezing the thing as much as possible. Probably, in this case, I'd just use `\mspace{-9mu}` or so on either side of the summation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
x \wedge y =
\sum_{\substack{
  1 \leq i_1 < \dots < i_p \leq n \\
  1 \leq j_1 < \dots < j_q \leq n
}}
a_{i_1 \ldots i_p} b_{j_1 \dots j_q}
\,
{\underbrace{e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_p} \wedge 
  e_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{j_q}}_{\text{is sometimes $0$}}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
x \wedge y =
\mathop{\sum\sum}_{\substack{
  1 \leq i_1 < \dots < i_p \leq n \\
  1 \leq j_1 < \dots < j_q \leq n
}}
a_{i_1 \ldots i_p} b_{j_1 \dots j_q}
\,
{\underbrace{e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_p} \wedge 
  e_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{j_q}}_{\text{is sometimes $0$}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\dots` should be used throughout: it yields the right kind of dots, in these cases.

The first rendering with a bit of back spacing:

```
\begin{equation*}
x \wedge y =
\mspace{-9mu}
\sum_{\substack{
  1 \leq i_1 < \dots < i_p \leq n \\
  1 \leq j_1 < \dots < j_q \leq n
}}
\mspace{-9mu}
a_{i_1 \ldots i_p} b_{j_1 \dots j_q}
\,
{\underbrace{e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_p} \wedge
  e_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{j_q}}_{\text{is sometimes $0$}}}
\end{equation*}
```

Pushing the subscript further under the equals sign would introduce ambiguities.

[image]

### A different version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

An \emph{ordered $n$-multiindex} is a finite sequence $(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_p)$, such that
\[
1\leq i_1<i_2<\dots<i_p\leq n.
\]
The set of $n$-multiindices is denoted by $M(n)$; for $I=(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_p)\in M(n)$ 
we also set
\[
e_I=e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_p}
\]
and note that we have actually proved that $\{e_I:I\in M(n)\}$ is a basis of the
exterior algebra $E(V)$, so any $x\in E(V)$ can be written in a unique way as
\[
x=\sum_{I\in M(n)}a_Ie_I
\]
for $a_I\in F$. Then, if $y=\sum_{J\in M(n)}b_Je_J$, we have
\begin{equation*}
x \wedge y =
\sum_{I,J\in M(n)} a_Ib_J e_I\wedge e_J
\end{equation*}
where $e_I\wedge e_J=0$ if $I$ and $J$ are not disjoint, that is, they have
some element in common.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many compliments. Very nice.

Comment: nice answer! Could you elaborate on why not to use `\smashoperator` ?

Comment: @hillbilly I added a solution with back spacing; compare it with the other using `\smashoperator`. I also added how I'd write the thing.

Comment: @egreg I see the result using `\mspace{-9mu}`. It is just less contracted. I suppose the comment to avoid smashoperator arises just from a readability plus if more spacing is allowed ?

Comment: @hillbilly: Please allow me to recommend that you adopt the notation with multiindices that egreg suggests under the title “A different version”: it is clearly superior to yours (no offense! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I would do it this way instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\ssum}{\sum\sum}

\begin{document}

   $ \displaystyle x \wedge y =
    \smashoperator{\ssum_{\substack{1 \leq i_1 < \dots < i_p \leq n \\1 \leq j_1 < \dots < j_q \leq n}}}
    a_{i_1 \dots i_p} b_{j_1 \dots j_q}
    \; \underbrace{e_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{i_p} \wedge e_{j_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{j_q}}_{\text{is sometimes 0}} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice too your answer.

Comment: some of those `\ldots` should be `\cdots`.  (see earlier comment.)  so use just `\dots`.  (you're using `amsmath`, so it will do the right thing.)

Comment: @barbara beeton: That's right. I had noticed it but didn't touch upon the O.P.'s code. I'll fix it in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\mathclap" macro
\begin{document}
\[
x\wedge y =
\mathop{\sum\sum}_{\mathclap{\substack{%
    1\leq i_1<\dots<i_p\leq n\\[2pt]
    1\leq j_1<\dots<j_q\leq n}}}
a_{i_1\dots i_p} b_{j_1 \dots j_q} \dots
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathoperator` gives an error for me.

Comment: @hillbilly - typo fixed.